# String to Data: Why use string.data(using: .utf8) over Data(string.utf8)

Tags: swift

When converting String to Data, the most common answer online is use `String.data(using:)`.

```swift
if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
    // process the data
}
```

Why not use `String.utf8` to convert the string into a `String.UTF8View` collection and initialize a `Data` instance with `Data.init(_:)`?

```swift
let data = Data(string.utf8)

// process the data
```

Neither `String.utf8` or `Data.init(_:)` return an optional, so no need for optional binding.

Comment: Because many people just don't know the API. `Data(string.utf8)` is state-of-the-art.

Comment: @vadian I remember when I figure that out in Swift 3 when Data started conforming to RandomAccessCollection. I've started spreading this approach a long time ago.

Comment: Note that converting string to utf8 will never fail so you can safely force unwrap the result

Comment: @vadian https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28132610/5 Apr 4 '17